# Should i include foreign key column in flutter model?

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I have created two tables like following code in sqflite database.

```
await database.execute("CREATE TABLE $debtorTABLE ("
      "debtorId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
      "name TEXT, "
      "mobileNumber TEXT "
      ")");

    await database.execute("CREATE TABLE $debtDetailsTable ("
      "debtId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
      "amount INTEGER, "
      "type TEXT, "
      "datetime TEXT, "
      "comments TEXT, "
      "FK_debtorId INTEGER, "
      "FOREIGN KEY(FK_debtorId) REFERENCES $debtorTABLE(debtorId)"
    ")");
```

And have created models for these two tables,

**1. Model for first table**

```
class Debtor {
  int debtorId;
  String name;
  String mobileNumber;

  Debtor({this.debtorId, this.name, this.mobileNumber});
  ................
  ...............
}
```

**2. Model for second table**

```
class Debtor {
      int debtId ;
      String amount;
      String type;
      String datetime;
      String comments; 
    *//Should i include foreign key here*
      Debtor({this.debtId, this.amount, this.type, this.datetime, this.comments });
      ................
      ...............
    }
```

Q: Should i include foreign key column in second model?. And also please correct me if any data type is wrong.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You should include debtorId as a foreign key column in the second table.

How will you know which debt belongs to which debtor if you do not?

Comment: Ok. Can you please check data types all are fine in table?